# how to read a file in awk command

Tags: linux, awk

I have two files that look like:

```
**file1.txt**

"a","1","11","111"

"b","2","22","222"

"c","3","33","333"

"d","4","44","444"

"e","5","55","555"

"f","6","66","666"

**file2.txt**

"b"

"d"

"a"

"c"

"e"

"f"
```

I need to create a script that changes the order of `file1` and begin with the order of `file2`. e.g.:

```
"b","2","22","222"

"d","4","44","444"

"a","1","11","111"

"c","3","33","333"

"e","5","55","555"

"f","6","66","666"
```

I created a command that looks like:

```
nawk '/^("b")/' file1 ; nawk '/^("d")/' file1 ; nawk '/^("a")/' file1 ; nawk '/^("c")/' file1 ; nawk '/^("e")/' file1 ; nawk '/^("f")/' file1
```

It does the trick, however I would like to further automate it, but don't know how to proceed.  How could I create a command or variable that would look at line 1 of `file2("b")` and put it the above command, then look at line 2 of `file2("d")`, and put it in the above command, and so on.  Basically if possible, I would like the command to look at file 2 and fill in the blanks in the above command. Any other more convenient commands you guys can suggest would be appreciated.  Note that I currently have to manually insert the letters from file 2 in the above command.

The actual file may contain well over 100 lines

Comment: Over 100 lines of input? Madness!!! :-). Are there really blank lines between every line of data in your input files? If no, fix your input to be more realistic. Either way, post the expected output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
awk -F, 'NR==FNR { a[$1]=$0; next }
    ($1 in a) { print a[$1] }' file1 file2
```

This reads all of `file1` into memory, then prints in the order of `file2`. If `file1` is very large, this may not be feasible.

This is a common Awk idiom; search the many near-duplicates if you need a more detailed explanation.

Comment: nope....your answer was perfect.  Thanks.  You saved me hours of inserting variables into my primitive code.